# What is this brick-based board game?

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm looking for the name of a board game from the 80's or 90's that was made up of yellow bricks in a small table that you had to tap out with a small red pick or hammer.

Comment: This is pretty vague. Any other details you can provide would be very helpful. Size, materials, object of the game, vertical or horizontal stacking..?

Comment: When I read brick-based game I immediately thought of Settlers of Catan... :-X

Answer (score 14):

Not yellow, but that sounds like Don't Break the Ice: [http://www.amazon.com/Hasbro-4784-Dont-Break-the/dp/B00000IVZJ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00000IVZJ)

---

These variations have yellow tiles:

- Summ Bumm (Spielkiste Bee edition)
  http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/1283724/dont-break-the-ice
- Wer andern eine Grube klopft (German First edition, 1976)
  http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/1070084/dont-break-the-ice

Comment: This fits my memory as well, and white bricks can easily yellow with age. (My poor Legos...)

Comment: I've added pictures of variants with yellow tiles.

Answer (score 8):

**Humpty Dumpty's Wall Game**?
[image: Image of Game]

Source:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Family-Game-Creative-Wall-Destroy-Game-Humpty-Dumpty-Wall-Game-Cube-Intelligent-Interactive-Play-with-Families/32836638151.html